# Xilinx ISE Project Navigator(nt64) and MVS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xilinx-ise

After "Generate programming file" for a easy FPGA LED project using the Xilinx 14.7 ISE (nt64) I got the following error:

```
Started : "Map".
Running map...
Command Line: map -intstyle ise -p xc6slx45-csg484-2 -w -logic_opt off -ol high -t 1 -xt 0 -register_duplication off -r 4 -global_opt off -mt off -ir off -pr off -lc off -power off -o LED_map.ncd LED.ngd LED.pcf

'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\include\map' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Process "Map" failed
```

I tried to solve the problem changing my path to:

```
PATH=C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\bin\nt64;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\lib\nt64;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\..\..\..\DocNav;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\PlanAhead\b
in;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\EDK\bin\nt64;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\EDK\lib\nt64;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\EDK\gnu\microblaze\nt\bin;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\EDK\gnu
\powerpc-eabi\nt\bin;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\EDK\gnuwin\bin;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\EDK\gnu\arm\nt\bin;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\EDK\gnu\microblaze\linux_toolchain\nt64_be\bin;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\EDK\gnu\microblaze\linux_toolchain\nt64_le\bin;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\common\bin\nt64;C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\common\lib\nt64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenNI\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL\bin;
```

However it doesn't work.

Looking in the folder of VisualStudio 2010 ('C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\include\map'), I found the map file, which obviously does not correspond to the map file looked for Xilinx ISE.

My fast and ugly solution was to change the name of the folder C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\include to C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\ _include

And finally Xilinx finds the corresponding map file and it works. However if I want to use VS2010 for other projects I need to rename the include folder again and "Generate programming file" in ISE doesn't work any more.

I was wondering if somebody can help me with a better solution to avoid that Xilinx looks for the file map in the include folder of MVC2010. It should find the map file directly in C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\bin\nt64.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround on LabVIEW's website:
http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/13219/en/#308548_by_Category

The Xilinx map program can crash if a file named "map" can be found anywhere on your system path.
When LabVIEW FPGA is running a compile, if a file named "map" can be found anywhere on your system path, then compilation will fail partway through. When compilation fails for this reason, the Xilinx log will contain an error with a message similar to the following: C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\include\map' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Process "Map" failed

Workaround: There are two workarounds.

1. Make a copy of the map.exe executables in your Xilinx bin directories.

   For example, for Xilinx 12.4 32-bit and 64-bit, make a copy of c:\NIFPGA\programs\xilinx12_4\ISE\bin\nt\map.exe in c:\NIFPGA\programs\xilinx12_4\ISE\bin\nt\map and a copy of c:\NIFPGA\programs\xilinx12_4\ISE\bin\nt64\map.exe in c:\NIFPGA\programs\xilinx12_4\ISE\bin\nt64\map.
2. Remove from your system path any directories that have files whose names match those of Xilinx executables but have no extension (i.e. map, par, trce, coregen). Restart the compile worker if it is running.